# How to set session ID in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, web, spring-security, flutter-web-browser

I am developing web application using flutter web, for server we are using spring, I need to implement login flow where captcha should be displayed which I receive from server as image, when user click on login button I am sending captcha answer and user credentials, but it getting failed in server side, reason session Id is null or empty.

I added logs at server application to check the incoming session ID from the front-end, every time API call is made for getting captcha and authenticate user, session is being received by server, but it is not same session ID which is being set for getting captcha and authenticate user.

I think login is getting failed as server is not receiving same session ID for captcha and authenticate user.

I tried storing the session ID from response headers but receiving null.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.